# Generate Pandas Series Based off of Base Value and Percentage Growth Rate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to generate a Pandas series that will start with two elements.

```
base_value = 100
growth_rate = .1
num_values = 4
```

to generate values values that grow from the base_value by the growth rate each time?
[100,110,121,133.1] etc etc

I thought that I might be able to use the shift function to grab the row above and then operate on that, but you can't shift a row on itself.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: `100 * (1.1**(np.arange(10))`?

Comment: What should be the `length` of your series?

Answer (score 1):

If `numpy` is option you might harness [geomspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html) like so

```
import numpy as np
start = 100
q = 1.1
count = 4
stop = start * q ** (count-1)
values = np.geomspace(start, stop, count)
print(values)
```

output

```
[100.  110.  121.  133.1]
```

Note that we have to calucate end value first, as it is compulsory for `numpy.geomspace`.